# Why does string.find() return -1?

Tags: python, string

For example:

```
theString = 'something whatsoever'
theString.find('what') # returns 10
```

However, when I find a string that is not in the string:

```
theString = 'something whatsoever'
theString.find('anything') # returns -1
```

What makes the `string.find()` function return -1?

Comment: that is how the function behavior is defined

Comment: The very definition of method makes it return -1. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find).

Comment: If it were 0, you couldn't distinguish "not found" from "found at the very beginning". And if you make it False, then people are liable to do things like `if re.find(...):`, and then 0 will behave *like* False.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think that last part is really the key. `if s.find(needle):` looks right, and would be right most of the time but not all of the time, which is pretty much the definition of an attractive nuisance. Returning -1 makes that obviously wrong, so anyone who tries it will discover their mistake immediately instead of months later while debugging. But also, there’s probably the safe that C functions like `strchr` and `strstr` already do it that way, or Guido would have just raised an exception for failure (and we wouldn’t have separate find and index methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.find()` returns -1 when the substring is not found in the string.

> [***`str.find(sub[, start[, end]])`***](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)
>   Return the lowest index in the string
>   where substring `sub` is found within the slice `s[start:end]`. Optional
>   arguments `start` and `end` are interpreted as in slice notation. ***Return
>   -1 if `sub` is not found***. (Emphasis mine)

But with that, comes with a note:

> **Note** The `find()` method should be used only if you need to know the
>   position of `sub`. To check if `sub` is a substring or not, use the `in`
>   operator:
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> 'Py' in 'Python'
> True
> ```

Comment: Thank you. I was expecting `False`, but it was not.

Comment: @PHD False is problematic.  In many languages, False and zero are the same (C), or nearly the same thing (Python).  However, zero is a valid result for find(), because Python uses zero based indexing, so it needs to be something else.   -1 is fairly standard convention for things that need to return "not found" when zero is a valid answer.

Comment: @Max I now understand how python gives out a false value. Really helpful.

Comment: @PHD In most cases like this (including the otherwise-identical `str.index`, which is also available on other sequences), Python returns failure by raising an appropriate exception. I suspect the main reason we have non-raising, -1 returning `str.find` as well is that C `strstr` does that. It’s how Guido presumably initially implemented `string.find`, so it would be in his head. Also, it makes it easier to translate C code snippets you find on Usenet into Python, even the ones that do silly tricks like a `if (!++pos) return result;` to break out of a loop after the last delimiter.